# How to make bootstrap nav-tabs headings editable?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have bootstrap `nav-tabs` with a `glphicon-pencil` beside every heading.On click of pencil I need to make the heading editable.

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
      <li class="active"><span></span><a data-toggle="tab" href="#home">Home<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></a></li>
      <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu1">Menu 1<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></a></li>
      <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu2">Menu 2<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></a></li>
    </ul>

    <div class="tab-content">
      <div id="home" class="tab-pane fade in active">
        <h3>HOME</h3>
        <p>Some content.</p>
      </div>
      <div id="menu1" class="tab-pane fade">
        <h3>Menu 1</h3>
        <p>Some content in menu 1.</p>
      </div>
      <div id="menu2" class="tab-pane fade">
        <h3>Menu 2</h3>
        <p>Some content in menu 2.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
```

fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/iamraviteja/jmsnrr5p/4/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just **want the contents to be edited**, you can do this:

```
$(".glyphicon-pencil").click(function() {
  $($(this).parent("a").attr("href")).attr("contenteditable", "true").focusout(function() {
    $(this).removeAttr("contenteditable").off("focusout");
  });
});
```

The above code will allow you to edit the **content**.

[Here is the **JSFiddle** demo](https://jsfiddle.net/m9hazgv1/)

If you just want the **headings to be edited**, then this is how I would have done it:

```
$(".glyphicon-pencil").click(function() {
  var pen = $(this);
  pen.css("visibility", "hidden");
  $(this).prev().attr("contenteditable", "true").focusout(function() {
    $(this).removeAttr("contenteditable").off("focusout");
    pen.css("visibility", "visible");
  });
});
```

[Here is the **JSFiddle** demo](https://jsfiddle.net/168eacmq/)

Comment: sorry my mistake,On click of pencil,the present content should appear as in textbox,where i could edit

Comment: @IamRaviteja I updated the answer and the link to [the JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/m9hazgv1/)

Comment: I want the headings to be editable,not the content.And pencil should not appear while editing

Comment: @IamRaviteja, confirm exact what u want, because thats what I did at first and you had me change it!